# JSON passed from custom URI scheme

Tags: c#, json, parameters, registry, uri

I've registered my Application to a custom URI Scheme using the instructions in this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm passing arguments to my programs using JSON and encoded by Uri.EscapeUriString method.

The problem is, quotation marks (") are encoded as %22, and if I open a link from a html page such as:

```
<a href="myapp://Args=%7B%20%22Id%22%3A1%2C%20%22Name%22%3A%22MyName%22%7D">link</a>
```

The original JSON (Before escaping URI string) is:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "MyName"
}
```

then it works fine, but only if I open it from Google Chrome.
If I open the same link from Internet Explorer 11, the quotation mark is not reserved, and therefore the JSON is invalid.

Is it an IE setting? Did anyone encountered it? I'm just using Uri.UnescapeURIString() function in the application to unescape the argument.